# Thymeleaf: Adding Database Content to Footer of Every Page. Best Practice?

Tags: database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**What is the best practice?**

I use `Spring-Boot` with `Thymeleaf` and want display an e-mail address as contact information on the bottom of each of my html pages. The e-mail address is stored in a `database` and may be changed at runtime.

**What I know:**

- I can use Thymeleaf fragments to create a footer with a hard-coded e-mail and include this footer to all my layouts. This works of course, but is not dynamic.
- I can perform a database query in the controller and add the e-mail to the model. The footer than gets the display string from the model. This will work too, but requires me to add the database query and model adding to all my controller’s functions. This would be a mess.

**What I don’t know:**

- Who do I solve this issue in an elegant way? I can implement a database call from Thymeleaf by accessing a SpringBean->returning the DB query. But this seems to be not right or is it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use so called **@ControllerAdvice** annotation. It can be used to add something to model attribute for every controller (depends how you specify it)

Define your test controller, which is in package "com.example.controller"

```
@Controller
public class ProductsController {
  @RequestMapping("/test")
  public String test(){
      return "test-page";
  }
}
```

Add global model

```
@ControllerAdvice("com.example.controller")
public class testAdvice {
  @ModelAttribute("email")
  public void addGlobalEmail() {
      return "some@email.com";
  }
}
```

You should be able to access ${email} on every template.

In controler advice you can inject you database service and take relevant data from there.

You can check this website for reference https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/controller-advice-with-model-attribute.html

Comment: Thx for your answer, it seems to be a real improvement in contrast to the mess of my second approach. I will give it a try, although I'm skeptical if it is best practice?